# Logic Connectives

Tags: logic

If for example I have two statements, a) I'm not old.  b) I'm not gay.
I can let O - I'm old and G - I'm gay and negate both. Using the same example in the book that I'm reading I can do it this way,

-(O ^ G) which means I'm not both old and gay. However it seems to me that it is more reasonable to say
-O ^ -G  or I'm not old and (I'm) not gay. However these two are not equivalent expressions since -(O ^ G) = -O v -G.

Which of the two should be used?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Which of the two is correct?

Comment: You should use whichever says what you are trying to say.  You are correct they are not equivalent.  Both are legal logical statements.

Comment: The two forms would either be different premises which could lead to different conclusions or different conclusions that come from different premises.  I don't understand what you are trying to ask.  "The car is blue" and "The car is green" are two different statements.  The one which should be used is the one that is correct or applicable to the argument at hand.

Comment: Saying "I am not (gay and old)" can be true when someone is a young gay or an old non-gay. It all depends on how you combine two separate statements.

Comment: everyday language has different conventions than math logic. I am not old or gay says the same as I am not old and I am not gay. You may want to come up with a new math formula -:(O,G) saying something along the lines that I am not any of the following: list old,gay. In everyday language the comma between old,gay is replaced by the word or. You are creating confusion (in the comments) as you did not state whether you were old or gay, and commenters cannot guess which is the case, and say which is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I tell you

> I am not both old and gay.

then I could be either old or gay, but not both.  That is
$$  \neg ( O \wedge G )  $$
is compatible (meaning , can be simultaneously true) with either $O$ or $G$, but not both.

If I tell you

> I am not old and I am not gay.

then I cannot be old, nor can I be gay.  That is
$$  \neg O \wedge \neg G  $$

is compatible neither with $O$ nor with $G$.

Now, de Morgan's Law applied to the sentence $\neg O \wedge \neg G$ gives $\neg (O \vee G)$.  That is, it turns "I am not old and I am not gay" into "I am not (either old or gay)."  It is a frequent deficiency of spoken language that there is no good way to speak the parentheses, so we use different constructions.  For instance, "Neither am I old or gay."  This sentence eliminates the possibility of the speaker being old and eliminates the possibility of the speaker being gay.  That is, this sentence is compatible neither with $O$ nor with $G$.

Comment: Thank you. After reading your response I realized I jumped to conclude that -(O ^ G)/ not both old and gay necessarily means NOT old and  NOT gay without considering the expression also makes sense when one isn't. (not old and gay / old and not gay). This is more of an english or grammar problem to me than math. I'm not a native english speaker also that's why.